# Forcing y-axis range in ui.Chart.image.series()

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, landsat-8, chart

I am harmonizing Landsat 8 and Sentinel-2 datasets for agricultural mapping purposes. When plotting the results using `ui.Chart.image.series` function, one graph shows the y-axis starting not at 0. For comparison purposes I need the y-axis on the charts to start at zero. How to adjust the below command to force y-axis to start at zero?

```
// Plot the fitted model and the original data at the ROI.
print(ui.Chart.image.series(fittedHarmonicboth.select(['fitted','NDVI']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10)
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Harmonic model: both S2 and L8 values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your options you should add the vAxis.minValue, such as:

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(fittedHarmonicboth.select(['fitted','NDVI']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10)
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Harmonic model: both S2 and L8 values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      vAxis: {minValue:0},
}));
```

More options are shown [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart).

Answer (score 0):

Add the limits with *`vAxis: {viewWindow: }}`*

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(fittedHarmonicboth.select(['fitted','NDVI']), roi, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10)
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Harmonic model: both S2 and L8 values',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      vAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 0}},
}));
```